# CSS - Bootstrap centering col-md-3 with weird results

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was having an issue center col-md-3 divs inside a wrapper. When I have 3 col-md-3 and use this code in my wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

the results are great! but when I have 11 col-md-3 each with a width of 25% its all jamed into a row and ignores the width, if they are 25% each I would like to have 3 per a row, not all on one. Is there away I can fix this?

```
.col-md-3 {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  width: 25%;
}

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
```

What I am expecting is to center these divs, they are each 25% in width, with justify-content: center; and display: flex it like it ignores the width so they are all in one row.

if I use `.center-block` with my `col-md-3` like so `<div class="col-md-3 center-block"></div>` it works, but it takes away my margin-right: 10px on my col-md-3, here is the CSS for center-block:

```
.center-block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

but it takes away the spacing between each col-md-3

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need to see the HTML to answer. It sounds like you aren't grouping the elements in a `<div class="row"></div>` wrapper..

Comment: I advice you not to  use bootstrap grid and flex together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the `col-` divs into `rows` in order for them to work properly: (also remember to close your divs)

`<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>`

Also, if you want 3 per row, i would suggest using `col-md-4`, as this will make things more easily centered if that is what you are going for.